# Create Azure AD ClientCredentials Key from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory, adal

In the Azure Portal I can create an Application, Key and Permissions to the Graph API.

I can get a Token using:

```
AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/graphDir1.onmicrosoft.com");
ClientCredential cc = new ClientCredential("b3b1fc59-84b8-4400-a715-ea8a7e40f4fe", "FStnXT1QON84B5o38aEmFdlNhEnYtzJ91Gg/JH/Jxiw=");
AuthenticationResult authResult = ac.AcquireToken("https://graph.windows.net", cc);
```

Using the [Azure Active Directory Module for Windows PowerShell](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=236297) I can create a new Symmetric Key.

```
New-MsolServicePrincipalCredential -AppPrincipalId ??? -Type Symmetric
```

Using the key returned from this in the code above returns the error:

```
AdalServiceException: AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50012: Invalid client secret is provided.
```

This used to work with a previous version of ADAL using instead of `ClientCredential`, `SymmetricKeyCredential` but that class no longer exists.

Is there a way to generate a key from PowerShell that works with the code above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try using `Password` as the key type:

```
New-MsolServicePrincipalCredential -AppPrincipalId $appId `
                                   -Type Password `
                                   -StartDate ([DateTime]::Now.AddMinutes(-5)) `
                                   -EndDate ([DateTime]::Now.AddMonths(1)) `
                                   -Value "$newPassword"
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Don't forget to clean up unused credentials with `Remove-MsolServicePrincipalCredential`!